# Chrome on Android is caching my video listed in manifest, but can't play it offline

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-appcache, offline-web-app

I've created an offline web app which shows in remote chrome debugging console as correctly caching all the files and it shows that it is correctly offline capable. The video, listed in the manifest shows as downloaded into the cache but when i turn on airplane mode and try to play, it shows an empty video.

How do I get a video to play offline?

Cache Manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
main.js
video.mp4
```

HTML link to manifest

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the only mobile browser that will play cached videos is Firefox on Android. *However*, there is a solution (For **Safari iOS8+, Chrome, Firefox** - I haven't tested IE) - **they will play a video blob in an objectURL even offline!**

What you do is this:

1. Create an indexedDB
2. Look for the stored video(s) in the db `request = transaction.objectStore( "myobjectstorename" ).get( savedId )`
3. Check the return, if there, move to step 5, otherwise step 4 `if ( !event.target.result ) downloadVideo()`
4. Download the video by running an `XMLHttpRequest` `GET` request and set the response type `videoRequest.responseType = "blob";`
5. When it's downloaded, retrieve it from the database *(step 2 above)* and put it into the document:

CODE To Put in page as object url:

```
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

//Make into a data URL
var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL( videoFile) ;

//Set video src to ObjectURL
document.getElementById( id ).setAttribute( "src", videoURL );
```

Modified the code from here:

http://www.misfitgeek.com/html5-off-line-storing-and-retrieving-videos-with-indexeddb/

Comment: Blob video playback doesn't work in Chrome on Android https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465

Comment: @artema it worked for me if i first store it in indexeddb.